# I can’t get the rest pose to reset without the rig glitching

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to rig a sword to the hand of my character, so I parented it to its own bone on the rig. I'm trying to reset the rest pose of the rig before I Parent the sword bone to the one in the hand, but when I try to do it, either the rig gets messed up so when it's in Edit Mode it's in the right pose, but in Object it's not. Or the mesh of the character doesn't move to the no rest pose but just moves to the original one. I would upload the file, but I don't know how because the upload function on the forum says the file is to big, and I had trouble zipping it when I tried.

Here is a link to the blend file.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/vtp2k9u0kisp6qi/Shape_man.blend/file

Comment: I have done the following:  if the blend file has lots of other objects and data, you may want to make a copy and delete items to reduce its size, and if it contains internal copies of texture images you can also jetison those with the File : External_Data : Unpack_All...

Comment: I do run into some "experiences" in armature animation (try duplicating a character and splitting off the poses is my latest).   Don't try to pose your character in edit mode -- that's for bone placement against the rest pose.   If the object pops back to a different pose in object mode from pose mode,  you may have something keyed in animation.   In object mode if you see animation on the bones (e.g., "spine_fk.001"), in timeline or other Animation editor, select all (or summary row keys) Delete Keyframes.  If nothing there, go back to pose mode, select all (bones) and Delete Keyframes.

Comment: I don't pose the character in edit mode, I simply tried to change the rest pose then went into edit mode to see that it worked but when I went into object mode the skeleton was in a different pose then the rest pose in edit mode, and trying to reset the pose in pose mode to rest did nothing. Also I added a link to the blend file, so you guys can take a look. Just try to change the rest pose of the character rig and you will hopefully see what I mean.

Comment: So I decided to trying changing the rest pose on another rig on a separate file that I had changed the rest pose on before on an older version of blender. The same thing happened on that rig, so clearly its not particular to that first rig, it must be something I'm doing wrong when trying to change the rest pose, now that I am using a newer build of Blender. I guess I don't know how to do it in 2.91.
So can someone walk me through how to, and avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm commenting here without any real knowledge of your rig, but on a straight forward affair the procedure isn't complex.  I've got some notes I made for myself yonks back.  You're welcome to those if you're still struggling with this.